# Check if webpage has a responsive navigation

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, navigationbar

Is there an intelligent way to check if a website has a responsive navigation? By responsive navigation I mean something like a full menu on a larger screen, and small menu button on a smaller screen, and the full menu would be toggled by this button.

An example is this image: http://osvaldas.info/incoming/images/blog/style_posts_m/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive-1.jpg

I want to run some jquery script for example to check if a webpage has such as menu. Something like testing if nav element has a really small width? Something more intelligent you can think of?

Comment: There are many ways someone could implement responsive design. So unless you want to look for a specific library, like Bootstrap, there's no general way to check for it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome, along with most common browsers, have something called Inspect Element. Right click on a page, or `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`F12`.

[image: Inspect Element]

You can even go ahead and click this button:

[image: Toggle]

Here you can simulate device resolutions:

[image: Simulate Resolutions]

Comment: I would like to check responsiveness programmatically.

Comment: Then I don't think you can. Understanding responsiveness is purely aesthetic and HCI-related for the most part. You can't detect that with a script.